# How to bind attribute to DropDownList Item on sever side to achieve getting multiple Date Values

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a `dropdownlist`, which is getting bind with the `datasource` on `page load`.

On `SelectedIndexChanged` event I need to get multiple values from `SelectedItem`

I don't want to get one value and call `database/session/viewstate` to get object with the value.

I search if I can add multiple `DataValueField` but seems it is not possible, Thus I am thinking to add an attribute to Item and assign additional value field to this attribute.

How can I bind attribute to `DDL` Item? I tried DataBinding event but don't know how to write code for it. Can anybody help? This is normal asp.net not `MVC`.

I also tried following (this works for Repeater control):

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="SetTypes" IsProfiled="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SiteID") %>" runat="server" Width="250" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:DropDownList>
```

but it seems Container does not have DataItem property.

Comment: Do you want to get multiple values for one selected item? Please be more descriptive. For instance, we could have a drodownlist with names countries names and values for each country an id. Then you could check a country, and get its id server side capturing this event. If you want to selecte multiple countries, then you should use List Item and set the option for multiple values. In your case what's the scenario?

Comment: I don't want to select multiple countries, I want to get countryid and one another field like countryid which is neither a DataText nor DataValue field.

Answer (score 0):

## Try this out:-

```
SetTypes.DataSource = new List<string>(){
    "Type1","Type2","Type3"};

SetTypes.DataBind();

foreach (ListItem item in SetTypes.Items)
{
    //Add multiple attributes
    item.Attributes.Add("CustomAttribue", "CustomValue");
}
```

Comment: my CustomValue will come from the data source

Comment: I tried this and verified that attributes is getting added in markup, but when i try to get this attribute in server side in SelectedIndexChanged event it is not found. My DropDownList is in UpdatePanel.