# Create Attribute for Dropdown list in markup for ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to be able to add an attribute to a drop-down list in ASP.NET in the markup if this is possible.
I am having the same issues as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20146701/how-to-bind-attribute-to-dropdownlist-item-on-sever-side-to-achieve-getting-mult).
The dynamically created code below does not persist on a postback.

```
protected void FormGV_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e){ 
...
listItem.Attributes.Add("DateOfService", form.sfc.DateOfThisService.ToString());
AnswerDD.Items.Add(listItem);
...
```

Then on a button click event I use the attribute but it is empty.

```
dateOfWork = AnswerDD.SelectedItem.Attributes["DateOfService"].ToDate();
```

I can confirm that the attribute is stored initially. I have researched the page lifecycle and am not entirely sure how to use what methods to add the dynamic code to have it persist. As you can see I use the RowDataBound method to dynamically create the attribute so I cannot use the PreInit method. So I wanted to create the attribute in the markup and then populate it dynamically.
I should add that when calling the Attribute the count of the attributes is 0 so it is not as if the attribute is empty, it just doesn't exist.

Comment: If you don't need that attribute on the client side, you could just maintain it on the server side only using something like viewstate. When the button is clicked you can just lookup the value using the selected item.

Comment: I just tested adding an attribute to a GridView control and then tried reading it on a button click. It is working as expected. So something else is the cause of not being able to read the property.

Answer (score -1):

To add an attribute to a dropdown list in ASP.NET markup and make sure it persists across postbacks, you can use the `ViewState` to store the attribute values. Here's an example of how you can achieve this:

1. Add an OnDataBound attribute to the GridView in your markup:

   ```html
   <asp:GridView ID="YourGridViewID" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="FormGV_RowDataBound" OnDataBound="GridView_DataBound">
       <!-- Your GridView markup here -->
   </asp:GridView>
   ```
2. In your code-behind, modify the `RowDataBound` event handler to store
   the attribute value in the `ViewState`:

   ```cs
   protected void FormGV_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
   {
       if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
       {
           DropDownList AnswerDD = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("YourDropDownListID"); // Replace with your actual DropDownList ID
           ListItem listItem = new ListItem("YourText", "YourValue");

           // Populate the DropDownList dynamically
           listItem.Attributes.Add("DateOfService", form.sfc.DateOfThisService.ToString());
           AnswerDD.Items.Add(listItem);

           // Store the attribute value in ViewState
           ViewState[AnswerDD.ClientID + "_DateOfService"] = form.sfc.DateOfThisService.ToString();
       }
   }
   ```
3. Implement the `OnDataBound` event handler to set the attribute value
   back on postback:

   ```cs
   protected void GridView_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       foreach (GridViewRow row in YourGridViewID.Rows)
       {
           if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
           {
               DropDownList AnswerDD = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("YourDropDownListID"); // Replace with your actual DropDownList ID

               // Retrieve the attribute value from ViewState and set it back
               if (ViewState[AnswerDD.ClientID + "_DateOfService"] != null)
               {
                   string dateOfService = ViewState[AnswerDD.ClientID + "_DateOfService"].ToString();
                   ListItem listItem = AnswerDD.Items.FindByValue("YourValue"); // Replace with your actual value
                   if (listItem != null)
                   {
                       listItem.Attributes["DateOfService"] = dateOfService;
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```